# $ionicLoading with Angular UI Router resolves

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use [$ionicLoading](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/) with Angular [UI Router resolves](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki). The idea being that when a new route/state is requested the loading modal appears while the data is being resolved, then disappears when the resolve completes and the new state is instantiated.

**router**

```
.state('tab.locations', {
  url: '/locations',
  cache: false,
  views: {
    'locations-tab': {
      templateUrl: 'js/locations/tab-locations.html',
      controller: 'LocationsCtrl as vm'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    locationsResource: 'Locations',
    locations: function(locationsResource) {
      return locationsResource.all();
    }
  }
})
```

Without the resolve, one recommended method is to use `$httpProvider.interceptors` to broadcast events to show and hide the loading screen. Like this:

**$ionicConfigProvider**

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');
      return config
    },
    response: function(response) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
      return response
    }
  }
})
```

**runBlock**

```
$rootScope.$on('loading:show', function() {
  $ionicLoading.show({template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'})
});

$rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function() {
  $ionicLoading.hide()
});
```

This works great when not using resolves. But when resolves work the loading screen no longer appears.

I have tried broadcasting `loading:show` on `$stateChangeStart` if a resolve is present but that also does not work.

Are there other interceptors or state change events I should be broadcasting `loading:show` and `loading:hide` on to make `$ionicLoading` work with resolves?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Nope, we ended up not using resolves.

Comment: wow. I'm having the same issue. I'm searching for a solution. I don't get the point of having the resolves if there is no loader.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this problem and this worked for me in the run block:

```
$rootScope.$on('loading:show', function () {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template:'Please wait..'
    })
});

$rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function () {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
    console.log('please wait...');
    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    console.log('done');
    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
});
```

I found it in the Ionic forum [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicloading-show-while-resolving-state-objects/16622/3)

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same problem. It works great with simple HTTP requests but when you start using state resolve it doesn't work out of the box.
You can use a simple module which works great by intercepting all of your $http requests.
https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar
This raises some events which you can use on **$rootScope.$on**.

**cfpLoadingBar:started** triggered once upon the first XHR request. Will trigger again if another request goes out after cfpLoadingBar:completed has triggered.

**cfpLoadingBar:completed** triggered once when the all XHR requests have returned (either successfully or not)

For someone still fighting with this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it in the app I'm developing:

```
export var ngModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

ngModule.run(($ionicPlatform: ionic.platform.IonicPlatformService, $state: ng.ui.IStateService, $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $ionicLoading: ionic.loading.IonicLoadingService) => {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => {
            $ionicLoading.show({
                delay: 200,
                template: "Loading..."
            });
        });

        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", (event, toState: ng.ui.IState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });

        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) => {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.error("Error loading the page: %o", error);
        });
        $state.go("login");
    });
});
```

It's in TypeScript, but I'm confident there is no problem to translate it to JavaScript.

Actually you don't need http interceptors nor to broadcast angular events.